# Conductive paint for ESD protection

Tags: esd, electrically-conductive, static-electricity

Will conductive paint applied to the inside of an ABS case prevent the case from getting electrically charged?
It was suggested to me to use a conductive plastic enclosure to prevent triboelectric charging, but they are not as easy to find in the form factor I want. So for aesthetic and practical reasons I want to paint the inside with conductive paint rather than the outside. Would this work?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "ESD protection?" Do you have an electronic product with an ABS housing, and you are wondering whether adding a conductive coating inside will help you pass ESD testing and prevent damage to the electronics? Please provide a bit more information so that you can receive better answers.

Comment: Please tell me what more information you need. Yes, I have an ABS housing, and no, I want to prevent triboelectric charging (charging by rubbing it on a table) so it does not zap people. This is stated in the original question. Protecting the electronics is already achieved by having a plastic case, the insulation voltage is quite high for such a case.

Comment: Normally when a person says "ESD protection" in the context of electronics, the idea is to protect the electronics from ESD. So I just wanted to confirm. I don't know the answer to your question, but, including your comment, I think the question is clear now. Maybe you can add the information from your comment to the question itself. As a side note, I have never seen or heard of an electronics device zapping people just because it is made of ABS. There are billions of electronic devices with ABS cases in the world, and most of them do not have conductive coatings on the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to prevent triboelectric charging (charging by rubbing it on a table) so it does not zap people.

[...]

> I want to paint the inside with conductive paint rather than the outside. Would this work?

No.

Now you have explained your aim is to prevent tribocharging on the outside of an insulating material (it wasn't clear originally whether you meant tribocharging the outside or inside). Making the *inside* of the case conductive, does not significantly affect the behaviour of the insulating material on the *outside*.

It isn't clear why there is so much rubbing of the case that tribocharging is actually a problem (tribocharging effects vary depending on the two materials involved - I'm surprised that rubbing on a table causes a problem...). However for the situation you describe, the options that I can see are either:

- change the material of the case; or
- apply a suitable anti-static coating to the outside of the case; or
- stop the rubbing of the outside of the case, which leads to the tribocharging; or
- change the material being rubbed on the case, to one which generates less charge with ABS.

Or, of course, accept your existing results as "expected behaviour" for devices with ABS cases, if you find other products / devices with similar cases, exhibit similar tribocharging in whatever test you are performing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For background: I am working on a medical device and this issue was raised by the notified body. IEC60601 and IEC62353 do state that there cannot be a body current larger than a certain threshold and I was assuming it is such an issue. But if their comment is 'only' regarding circuit protection, we can deal with it in risk management.

Comment: @zorgmorg, the application being a medical device would have been useful information to include in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I work building test gear for testing electronic products. We are often concerned with this issue because we don't want the device being tested to be damaged by a static discharge from the test equipment.

> Will conductive paint applied to the inside of an ABS case prevent the case from getting electrically charged?

It will prevent the inner surface of the case from getting charged, but will do nothing to prevent charge build up on the outer surface.

> So for aesthetic and practical reasons I want to paint the inside with conductive paint rather than the outside. Would this work?

I expect not.